# 'GetAll' method in my API returning null values, but the query works in db/C#

Tags: c#, database, join

I have this GetAll method in my API which should return all entries in my DB. But it’s only returning from the joined tables Genre and Location. So the Book attributes are missing.

So as you can see, it’s missing all the Book Attributes and only taking in from Genre and Location:

```javascript
[
  {
    "bookId": 1,
    "title": "",
    "author": "",
    "genre": {
      "genreId": 6,
      "genreName": null
    },
    "noOfPages": 0,
    "bookType": "",
    "isbnNo": "",
    "location": {
      "locationId": 1,
      "locationName": "Nibe                                                        "
    },
    "status": "",
    "bookImagesPath": []
  },
  {
    "bookId": 2,
    "title": "",
    "author": "",
    "genre": {
      "genreId": 6,
      "genreName": null
    },
    "noOfPages": 0,
    "bookType": "",
    "isbnNo": "",
    "location": {
      "locationId": 2,
      "locationName": "Skørping                                                    "
    },
    "status": "",
    "bookImagesPath": []
  },
  {
    "bookId": 3,
    "title": "",
    "author": "",
    "genre": {
      "genreId": 6,
      "genreName": null
    },
    "noOfPages": 0,
    "bookType": "",
    "isbnNo": "",
    "location": {
      "locationId": 3,
      "locationName": "Søborg                                                      "
    },
    "status": "",
    "bookImagesPath": []
  },
  {
    "bookId": 4,
    "title": "",
    "author": "",
    "genre": {
      "genreId": 6,
      "genreName": null
    },
    "noOfPages": 0,
    "bookType": "",
    "isbnNo": "",
    "location": {
      "locationId": 4,
      "locationName": "Aalborg                                                     "
    },
    "status": "",
    "bookImagesPath": []
  }
]
```

The *GetAll* method:

```csharp
public async Task<List<Book>> GetAll()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var books = new List<Book>();
            string bookQuery = @"SELECT
                                     b.bookId, b.genreId,
                                     b.locationId, b.isbnNo,
                                     b.title, b.author,
                                     b.noOfPages, b.bookType,
                                     b.status,
                                     l.locationName,
                                     g.GenreId, g.GenreName
                                 FROM Book b
                                 INNER JOIN Genre g ON b.genreId = g.genreId
                                 LEFT JOIN Location l ON b.locationId = l.locationId";

            books = (await conn.QueryAsync<Book, Genre, Location, Book>(bookQuery,
                    (book, genre, location) => {
                        book.Genre = genre;
                        book.Location = location;
                        return book;
                    },

                    transaction: transaction,
                    splitOn: "GenreId,LocationId"))
                .ToList();

            transaction.Commit();

            return books; // Return the populated list of books
        }
    }
}

namespace Model
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
        public string BookType { get; set; }
        public string IsbnNo { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<string>? BookImagesPath { get; set; }

        public Book() { }

        public Book(int bookId, string title, string author, Genre? genre, int noOfPages, string bookType, string isbnNo, Location? location, string status, List<string>? bookImagesPath = null)
        {
            BookId = bookId;
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
            Genre = genre;
            NoOfPages = noOfPages;
            BookType = bookType;
            IsbnNo = isbnNo;
            Location = location;
            Status = status;
            BookImagesPath = bookImagesPath;
        }

        public Book(string title, string author, Genre? genre, int noOfPages, string bookType, string isbnNo, Location? location, string status, List<string>? bookImagesPath = null)
        {
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
            Genre = genre;
            NoOfPages = noOfPages;
            BookType = bookType;
            IsbnNo = isbnNo;
            Location = location;
            Status = status;
            BookImagesPath = bookImagesPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Database for Book:

```sql
USE [BookLibrary]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book]
(
    [bookId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [genreId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [locationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isbnNo] [nchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [author] [nchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [noOfPages] [int] NOT NULL,
    [bookType] [nchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [status] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([bookId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Book] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Book_Genre]
        FOREIGN KEY ([genreId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Genre] ([genreId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Book] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Book_Genre]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Book] WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Book_Location]
        FOREIGN KEY ([locationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([locationId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Book] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Book_Location]
GO
```

[DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object):

```csharp
using Model;

namespace DTOs
{
    public class BookOutDto
    {
        public int? BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
        public string BookType { get; set; }
        public string IsbnNo { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<string> BookImagesPath { get; set; }

        public BookOutDto() { }

        public BookOutDto(int? bookId, string title, string author, Genre genre, int noOfPages, string bookType, string isbnNo, Location location, string status, List<string> bookImagesPath)
        {
            BookId = bookId;
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
            Genre = genre;
            NoOfPages = noOfPages;
            BookType = bookType;
            IsbnNo = isbnNo;
            Location = location;
            Status = status;
            BookImagesPath = bookImagesPath;
        }
    }

    public class BookInDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public int NoOfPages { get; set; }
        public string BookType { get; set; }
        public string IsbnNo { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<string>? BookImagesPath { get; set; }

        public BookInDto() { }

        public BookInDto(string title, string author, Genre genre, int noOfPages, string bookType, string isbnNo, Location location, string status, List<string> bookImagesPath)
        {
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
            Genre = genre;
            NoOfPages = noOfPages;
            BookType = bookType;
            IsbnNo = isbnNo;
            Location = location;
            Status = status;
            BookImagesPath = bookImagesPath;
        }
    }
}

using DTOs;
using Model;

namespace BusinessLogic.ModelConversion
{
    public class BookDtoConvert
    {
        public static Book? FromDtoToBook(BookInDto bookDto)
        {
            Book? convertedBook = null;

            if (bookDto != null)
            {
                convertedBook = new Book(
                    bookDto.Title,
                    bookDto.Author,
                    bookDto.Genre,
                    bookDto.NoOfPages,
                    bookDto.BookType,
                    bookDto.IsbnNo,
                    bookDto.Location,
                    bookDto.Status,
                    bookDto.BookImagesPath
                    );
            }

            return convertedBook;
        }

        public static BookOutDto? FromBookToDto(Book bookModel)
        {
            BookOutDto? bookOut = null;

            if (bookModel != null)
            {
                bookOut = new BookOutDto(
                    bookModel.BookId,
                    bookModel.Title ?? string.Empty,
                    bookModel.Author ?? string.Empty,
                    bookModel.Genre,
                    bookModel.NoOfPages,
                    bookModel.BookType ?? string.Empty,
                    bookModel.IsbnNo ?? string.Empty,
                    bookModel.Location,
                    bookModel.Status ?? string.Empty,
                    bookModel.BookImagesPath ?? new List<string>()
                );
            }

            return bookOut;
        }

        public static List<BookOutDto>? FromBookDtoToList(List<Book> bookModels)
        {
            List<BookOutDto>? aListOfDtos = null;

            if (bookModels != null)
            {
                aListOfDtos = new List<BookOutDto>();
                BookOutDto tempDto;

                foreach (Book book in bookModels)
                {
                    if (book != null)
                    {
                        tempDto = FromBookToDto(book);
                        aListOfDtos.Add(tempDto);
                    }
                }
            }

            return aListOfDtos;
        }
    }
}

namespace Model
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string GenreName { get; set; }

        public Genre() { }

        public Genre(int genreId, string genreName)
        {
            GenreId = genreId;
            GenreName = genreName;
        }
    }
}

namespace Model
{
    public class Location
    {
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }

        public Location() { }

        public Location(int locationId, string locationName)
        {
            LocationId = locationId;
            LocationName = locationName;
        }
    }
}
```

Genre in database:

```sql
USE [BookLibrary]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Genre]
(
    [genreId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [genreName] [nchar](60) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Genre]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([genreId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location]
(
    [locationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [locationName] [nchar](60) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Location]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([locationId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample insert data:

```
1    6    1    978-1-292-15902-1                                               Objects First with Java                                         David J. Barnes                                                 630    Paperback                                                       Læst
2    6    2    978-87-993382-3-8                                               Bogen om C#                                                     Michell Cronberg                                                368    Paperback                                                       Læst
3    6    3    0-321-20568-5                                                   User Stories Applied                                            Mike Cohn                                                       264    Paperback                                                       Ulæst
4    6    4    978-1-292-09613-1                                               Software Engineering                                            Ian Sommerville                                                 810    Paperback                                                       Ulæst
```

I tried modifying the DTO and model classes and debug, where I can see it does not get the missing attributes.

Comment: Woa! That was a lot of code! I guess there is a database somewhere where you can run the sql query directly. Do that and verify the output is what you expect. Also; add a tag for the library you are using - Dapper? Microsoft?

Comment: Your "Sample insert data" does not have column names, so a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/EQax3XpQ) will only return no results.   (Hint: you can add the data to that dbfiddle, and post a link to that with a reproduction of your problem)

Comment: There is also the concept of an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the list of columns you have selected, `genreId` and `locationId` come immediately after the `bookId`. But you've instructed Dapper to `splitOn` `LocationId` and `GenreId`. So when it hits the `genreId` column, Dapper figures you're done reading Book properties and switches to reading Genre properties. Then it hits `locationId` and starts reading `Location` properties. That's why Book and Genre only have ID properties filled in, while Location has all of its properties.

You need to organize your `SELECT` fields so everything you want on the Book comes before the field matching your first `splitOn` field name. Then everything from Genre, then everything from Location.